# How to test if the input is a positive fraction?

Tags: core-language

I would like to check if a fraction is positive. The difficulty arises when there are symbols. I would like to make the assumption that all symbols, variables, and indeterminates are positive real numbers for example a function named PositiveFractionQ would return False when

```wl
PositiveFractionQ[-(p*q*r)/(red*green*blue)]
```

is evaluated, but True when

```wl
PositiveFractionQ[(p*q*r)/(red*green*blue)]
```

is evaluated.
How can I do this?

Comment: `myPositive[expr_] := Assuming[Variables[Level[expr, {-1}]] \[Element] PositiveReals, Simplify[expr > 0]]`

Comment: Not my -1, but I can't grok the significance. $\Bbb Q$ is the field of fractions of $\Bbb Z$. Rational functions are the field of fractions of polynomials. Each has a justified existence and importance. Fractions of real numbers do not seem important. Unless the goal is the proliferation of functions, or the proliferation of TL Q&A.

Answer (score -4):

Define a function that makes assumptions.

```wl
PositiveExpressionAssumingAllVariablesArePositiveRealsQ[input_] := 
 Refine[Positive[input], {Element[Variables[input], PositiveReals]}]
```

Then do this to check if the input is a fraction.

```wl
FractionQ[input_] := Denominator[input] =!= 1 && ! ListQ[input]
```

This will check if the input is a positive fraction.

```wl
PositiveFractionQ[input_] := 
 MatchQ[input, (fraction_)?FractionQ /; 
   MatchQ[Numerator[fraction], _?
     PositiveExpressionAssumingAllVariablesArePositiveRealsQ]]
```

There is a bug where

```
(f q^(3/4 + j/2) Sqrt[a^(3/2)/(b c d z)] \[Rho])/g
```

does not return True.
I'm not sure how to fix this.

I fixed the bug.
Use this instead.

```wl
PositiveExpressionAssumingAllVariablesArePositiveRealsQ[input_] := 
 FullSimplify[input > 0, {Element[Variables[input], PositiveReals]}]
```

For a negative fraction, do this.

```wl
NegativeFractionQ[input_] := 
 MatchQ[input, 
  fraction_?FractionQ /; 
   MatchQ[Numerator[fraction], _?
     NegativeExpressionAssumingAllVariablesArePositiveRealsQ]]
NegativeExpressionAssumingAllVariablesArePositiveRealsQ[input_] := 
 FullSimplify[input < 0, 
  Assumptions -> {Variables[input] \[Element] PositiveReals}]
```

Comment: Try `PositiveFractionQ[a^b/c]`. You might be interested in ``Integrate`getAllVariables[a^b/c, {}]``. [Best practice is usually held to be to avoid starting user-defined symbol names with a capital letter.]